# Why is it possible to convert a non-constant value x to type T when x is NOT assignable to T?

Tags: go

According to Go spec a non-constant value x can be converted to type T if x is assignable to T (first rule out of 7).

Given the following 2 codes:

1. successfully convert:

> ```
> type T int
> var x int
> _ = T(x)
> ```

2. failing to assign x to T (same x and T as above):

> ```
> type T int
> var x int
> var t T = x
> ```

Why is it possible to convert x to T while x is not assignable to t?

Is it  because of the second conversion rule which state "ignoring struct tags, x's type and T have identical underlying types.", but isn't that rule only relevant to structs? (I may be misled by the examples I saw at the spec and other places...).

Comment: Yes, it is because of that rule, and no, it's not just structs. "x's type and T have identical underlying types" does not mention structs, only types.

Comment: OK good to know and thanks :)